# Update field in sql to first day of the next month

Tags: mysql

I have sql commands that set a future date based on events that happened in the past. Currently, it sets the future date to 365 days from the past date. Would there be a way to have it round the date up to the 1st day of the next month? I have tried to use the EOMONTH function but have not been able to successfully integrate it into my current statements. I have three different scenarios for setting the date:

1st Scenario:

```
UPDATE `buildiumdata_leases` SET `Next_increase_date` = CASE
                WHEN Last_increase_date is NULL and Type = 'At Will' THEN DATE_ADD(Start_date , INTERVAL 365 DAY)
                ELSE `Next_increase_date`
               END
```

2nd Scenario:

```
UPDATE `buildiumdata_leases` SET `Next_increase_date` = CASE
                WHEN Last_increase_date is NULL and Type != 'At Will' THEN DATE_ADD(End_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                  ELSE `Next_increase_date`
               END
```

3rd Scenario:

```
UPDATE `buildiumdata_leases` SET `Next_increase_date` = CASE
                WHEN (Last_increase_date < Future_increase_date OR Last_increase_date is NULL) AND Future_increase_date IS NOT NULL THEN Future_increase_date
                ELSE `Next_increase_date`
               END
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the date_format() function like

```
date_format(yourdatecolumn, ‘%Y-%m-01‘)
```

This will give you the first of the current month. If you need the next add one month with date_add

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me with a little adjusting.